# How to fix this EInvalidPointer error while translating Free Pascal into Delphi?

Tags: delphi

We are tring to use in delphi a pas file generated by Free Pascal. The link is at:
http://www.markwatson.com/opensource/FastTag_Pascal.zip

While testing, it prompts InValidPointer. Please look at the following error line in debugger.

```
interface

procedure ReadLexicon;
type sarray = array[1..12] of string;
type big_sarray = array[1..1000] of string; { used for word lists and tags: limit on size of input text }
type psarray = ^sarray;

{function GetTagList(word: string): psarray;}
procedure TagWordList(wordList : big_sarray; var tags : big_sarray);

implementation

uses SysUtils, Classes;

 {       Hash Table Support - copied from FreePascal source: benchmork shootout examples }

type
   THashEntryPtr = ^THashEntryRec;
   THashEntryRec = record
      name : string;
      number : psarray;
      next : THashEntryPtr;
   end;

const
   TABLE_SIZE = 100000;

...
...
...
function GetTagList(word: string): psarray;
var
ret : psarray;
ok : boolean;
begin
 ok := localHash.fetch(word, ret);
 if ok then GetTagList := ret else GetTagList := nil;
end;

procedure TagWordList(wordList : big_sarray; var tags : big_sarray);
var i : integer;
    x : real;
    psa : psarray;
    lastThreeChars : string;
    lastTwoChars : string;
    lastChar : string;
    firstTwoChars : string;
    tagFirstTwoChars : string;
    begin
 for i := 0 to length(wordList) do
  begin
   **psa := GetTagList(wordList[i]);///// EInvalidPointer ERROR** 
   if psa <> nil then tags[i] := psa^[1] else tags[i] := '???';
  end;

...
...
...
```

How can we fix it.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original source doesn't set any compiler mode, and so the default TP like mode is active, meaning string=shortstring.

Replace, in the entire source string with shortstring and it will probably work.

Comment: Dear Marco van de Voort, it works now, though i still do not know why it should be replaced as you advised, and it seems very slow to load that lexicon file and run. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two errors I can find in the TagWordList procedure.

1. `for i := 0 to length(wordList) do`, the array is 1-based so the loop has to start with 1.
2. A bit later there is a check `if i > 0` that fails for the same reason.

It could also be a wrong definition of the type `big_sarray = array[1..1000] of string;`. If you change that to a 0-based array it might work.